# How do I call a static property on a Swift protocol from a generic function?

Tags: swift, generics

Given this code:

```
public protocol Selectable {

    typealias T

    var selected: Bool { get }

    static var defaultValue: T { get }

}

public func selected<T: Selectable>(items: [T]) -> T {
    if let selected = items.filter({$0.selected}).first {
        return selected
    }
    return T.defaultValue
}
```

I get an error on the return line: "Cannot convert return expression of type 'T.T' to expected return type 'T'".

Changing it to `return T.defaultValue as! T` seems to work but that doesn't make any sense to me. Am I missing something or should I file a radar?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Self` in the protocol:

```
public protocol Selectable {

    var selected: Bool { get }

    static var defaultValue: Self { get }
    //                       ^^^^
}

public func selected<T: Selectable>(items: [T]) -> T {
    if let selected = items.filter({$0.selected}).first {
        return selected
    }
    return T.defaultValue
}
```

---

OR, if you want to use `typealias`, you have to:

```
public protocol Selectable {
    typealias Value

    var selected: Bool { get }

    static var defaultValue: Value { get }
}

public func selected<T: Selectable where T.Value == T>(items: [T]) -> T {
    //                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if let selected = items.filter({$0.selected}).first {
        return selected
    }
    return T.defaultValue
}
```

Comment: Aha, because the declaration of the generic function doesn't know what T is (at all, ever? Or at least not at compile time) but the protocol does? Or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, in your code `selected` function doesn't know what the actual type of `typealias T`. `T` in the `selected` function and `T` in the `Selectable` is not related.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @rintaro's answer, using `Self` for the type of `defaultValue` means the `typealias` is unnecessary:

```
public protocol Selectable {

    var selected: Bool { get }

    static var defaultValue: Self { get }

}

public func selected<T: Selectable >(items: [T]) -> T {
    if let selected = items.filter({$0.selected}).first {
        return selected
    }
    return T.defaultValue
}
```

(I found this as changing `defaultValue`'s type to `Self` made my implementing class not conform to the protocol anymore—and I noticed I wasn't even referring to the `typealias Value`; removing that made my implementing class comply again.)